# How to write an object inside a table's cell in a feature file?

Tags: java, cucumber, gherkin

What I want is:

```
Then verify the following search task summery:
  | list of objects                                       | more columns... |
  | {property1: 1, property2: "hi", property3: true}, {property1: 1, property2: "hi", property3: true}              | .... |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did some research and although I haven't used such objects inside a .feature file below are a few things you could try if you haven't already.

A few things you could try:

- If you really want to use that list and there is no other way, just handle it in the step definition as a `String` and change it however you want. Check out this [link](http://toolsqa.com/cucumber/maps-in-data-tables/)
- Make the data table different again manage it in the step definition. An example would be:

Then verify the following search task summery:

```
| Property1 | Property2 | Property3 |
| 1         | hi        | true      |
| 2         | hello     | false     |
```

---

Have a look [here](https://docs.cucumber.io/cucumber-expressions/) and [here](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Step-Argument-Transforms) for more details on this subject.

There might be different ways to do this and I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Don't even try instead find a name for your list of objects e.g. empty_properties and write a step that uses that name

`Then I should see the empty properties`

Then you can get your list of properties from a number of places

1. The tests, create a helper method to return the expected result
2. An external source
3. Your application (this is the best one, if it makes sense)

Trying to put the details of what you should receive in scenarios has many difficulties

- reading the details and knowing they are correct is very difficult
- its very hard to express anything complex
- it makes the step definitions much much harder to write
- it significantly increases the cost of change, as every time a detail changes in your object you have to update your scenario (your scenario is now tightly coupled to your object definition.

Scenarios are not a place for details about how something is done if you are writing lots of tables, scenario outlines and complex values in your scenarios you are cuking wrong :)